# Rotating Posts on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to rotate posts. It shows first one and stops. Can someone help please?

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Image Gallery', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    echo '<li><span>';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</span><div><h3>Title</h3></div></li>';
    echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
?>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Could you try to clarify more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Its stopping at the first post because you have  set `'posts_per_page' => 1`, set this to either -1 for all the posts or a specific number

Comment: Are you trying to show post by Random?

Comment: I want an image slider to rotate Image 1 - 5 for example.